# Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, object given

Tags: php

how do i solve error message

> Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource,
>   object given

my code :

```
if(isset($_POST['login']))
    {
        $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
        $password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);

        $res = $MySQLiconn->query(" SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username' ");
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($res);

        if($row['password'] == md5($password))
        {
            $_SESSION['login'] = $row['user_id'];
            echo $_SESSION['login'];
        }
        else
        {
            echo "<script>alert('wrong details')</script>";
        }


    }
```

Can anyone help ?

Comment: Did you tried to var_dump $res ?

Comment: Mixing mysqli and mysql

Comment: SHow your form and database connection code!!

Comment: as @Saty mentioned already, try to change `mysql_fetch_array` to `mysqli_fetch_assoc` and see if it fixes your issue.

Comment: also `mysql_real_escape_string` to `mysqli_real_escape_string`

Comment: how can you be sure if the OP is using `mysqli`?? Note that `$MySQLiconn` is just a variable here not the actual `mysqli` function

Comment: WE need more input form OP side

Answer (score 1):

The actual problem is you are mixing `mysqli` methods and `mysql` methods together.

`$res = $MySQLiconn->query(" SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username' ");`

is in mysqli and

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array($res);
```

is in mysql. so here you are passing `$res` which is an `object` `mysqli::query` returns an object and `mysql_fetch_array()` expects a resource that is why it shows such an error. .  So either use `mysql` or use `mysqli` to resolve the problem.

Comment: how can you be sure if the OP is using `mysqli`?? Note that `$MySQLiconn` is just a variable here not the actual `mysqli` function

Comment: mysql_query will not return an object `Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, object given` is the error...

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing `mysql` and `mysqli` calls in your code. Use `mysqli_fetch_array` instead of `mysql_fetch_array.`

Comment: how can you be sure if the OP is using `mysqli`?? Note that `$MySQLiconn` is just a variable here not the actual `mysqli` function